# How to count the length of each word in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am a Grade 10 IT student, so I am relatively new to Delphi. I need to make a program that receives a sentence as input from an edit box. The number of words and the length of each. I can find the position of the first space in the sentence but do not know how to find each space.

Can anyone help?

Comment: May be easier to use a split function

Comment: Or you might iterate through the string?

Answer (score 4):

It depends which Version of Delphi do you use. Here are 2 possible solutions:

1. All Delphi Versions:

> ```
> var input : string;
>     aword : string;
>     r: Integer;
>     allowedchars : set of 'A'..'z';
> begin
>   allowedchars:=['A'..'z'];
>   ListBox1.Clear;
>   input:='This is my test sentence. Feel free to count words, or let it count!';
>   for r := 1 to Length(input) do begin
>     if(input[r] in allowedchars)then begin
>       aword:=aword+input[r];
>     end else begin
>       if(length(aword)>0)then
>       ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('%s: %d',[aword,Length(aword)]));
>       aword:='';
>     end;
>   end;
> end;
> ```

2. Newer Delphi Versions, from XE3 on

> ```
> var input : string;
>     words : TArray<string>;
>     aword : string;
> begin
>   ListBox1.Clear;
>   //1. Use the Split Helper Method, from XE3 and newer Delphis
>   input:='This is my test sentence. Feel free to count words, or let it count!';
>   words:=input.Split(['.',';',',','!','?',' '],TStringSplitOptions.ExcludeEmpty);
>   ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('Words: %d',[Length(words)]));
>   for aword in words do begin
>     ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('%s: %d',[aword,aword.Length]));
>   end;
> end;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `TStringList` class to split a string into substrings with a specified [Delimiter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Delimiter) property and the `DelimitedText` method.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,Classes;

procedure CheckString( const someText: String; var wordLength: TArray<Integer>);
var
  aList: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  aList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    aList.Delimiter := ' ';  // Define the delimiter
    aList.DelimitedText := someText;  // Split the text
    SetLength(wordLength,aList.Count);  // Set the result word count
    for i := 0 to Pred(aList.Count) do
    begin
      wordLength[i] := Length(aList[i]);    // Set the word length
    end;
  finally
    aList.Free;
  end;
end;

var
  s: String;
  counter: TArray<Integer>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  s := 'This is a  test.';
  CheckString(s,counter);
  WriteLn('Found words:',Length(counter));
  for i := 0 to Pred(Length(counter)) do
    WriteLn(counter[i]);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

If you are using an older version of Delphi, replace `TArray<Integer>` with `TIntegerDynArray` defined in the `Types` unit.
And in old Delphi-7 you must declare it yourself:

```
Type
  TIntegerDynArray = array of Integer;
```

If you want to exclude some characters from your string before the split, use this function:

```
function StripChars(const aSrc, aCharsToStrip: string): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := aSrc;
  for i := 1 to Pred(Length(aCharsToStrip) do
    Result := StringReplace(Result, aCharsToStrip[i], '', 
      [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
end;

// Example call
myString := StripChars(s,'.,!?;');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find the `posex` function very useful...if it's part of D7

Otherwise, look for the `delete` function or `copy` function.